# Confidence of association rules

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

Trying to understand an assignment I did not do correctly.

Assume all the (closed) frequent itemsets and their support counts are:

- Support( {A, B, C, D} ) = 0.3
- Support( {A, B, C} ) = 0.4
- What is Conf(B -> ACD) = ?
- What is Conf(A -> BCD) = ?
- What is Conf(ABD -> C) = ?
- What is Conf(BD -> AC) = ?

I was under the impression that for {confidence a -> bcd}, I could just do .4/.3 .... obviously incorrect, as support cannot be greater than 1.

Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confidence(B -> ACD) is the support of the combination by the antecedent. So Support(ABCD)/Support(B). You'll notice that Support(B) is not given explicitly, but you can infer the value via closedness.

So the result is 0.3/0.4 = 75%

Note that support is usually given in absolute terms, but of course that doesn't matter here.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. I was flipping the two around and getting support > 1. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the following definitions for support and confidence formulated in an informal way.

Support(X) = Number of times the itemset appears together / Number of examples in the dataset

Conf(X -> Y) = Support(X union Y)/Support(X)

Applying the definition we have:

- Conf(B -> ACD) = Support(ABCD)/Support(B)
- Conf(A -> BCD) = Support(ABCD)/Support(A)
- Conf(ABD -> C) = Support(ABCD)/Support(ABD)
- Conf(BD -> AC) = Support(ABCD)/Support(BD)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Thanks for writing out the definitions - I was flipping the two.